# How to show loader while drop files in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, draggable, drop

I am creating a mass upload feature so that user can drag drop multiple files (500 plus) at a time, but when I am dropping 500 plus files in drop div then for few seconds my screen freezes and the user is unable to understand what is actually happening.

I decided to show a loader image while drag but it is not working.

```js
$("#div").on("drop", function (e) {
    EnableLoader(); //this will show a loader image on screen but its not working here
    if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle? Or share the code for `EnableLoader()` and the HTML.

Comment: EnableLoader() is doing nothing special it is just displaying a div which has a spinner circle image.
 function EnableLoader(){jQuery("#page-loader").addClass('d-flex')}